# How to get the first value to be default in select option

Tags: html

How to get the first value to be default value. In the select option values I have taken a loop for the multiple values. Now I want to select the first values by default but in a way that the last value is always selected by default. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you show us your code? Maybe even set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

try `<option value="1" selected="selected">xyz</option>`

Comment: <option value='' disabled='disabled' selected>Select</option>
         {% for role in role_list %}
 <option value="{{role.1}}" selected="selected">{{role.0}}</opton>
         {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add the selected attribute to the option u want to be selected

```
<select>
<option selected="selected"  value="1">selected option1</option>
<option  value="2">option2</option>
<option value="3">option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You do realise that selects the second value rather than the first?

Comment: I have used the same but always last value is selected as default i want the first value to be default when using for loop .

Comment: my code is :<option value='' disabled='disabled' selected>Select</option> {% for role in role_list %} <option value="{{role.1}}" selected="selected">{{role.0}}</opton> {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

use `selected` attribute for your first option